# SQL Power Architect Mondrian Schema: Creating two cubes with the same dimensions

Tags: sql, sql-server, mondrian

I am trying to create two cubes in the SQL Power Architect OLAP Schema Editor.

Each of these cubes use separate tables but they will have similar values for dimensions.  For example each of these tables has a column with date, version #, name, and ID.

Is it possible to have each of the cubes pointing at the same dimension(Date for cube one pointing at dimension A, date for cube two also pointing at dimension A)

Or would I have to create entirely separate dimensions for each cube?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Mondrian supports such constructs. You should read about Shared Dimensions and Dimension Usage.

As for SQL Power Architect, I can't recall if you can do it from there.